# Minimizing a quadratic-over-linear fractional function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, rational-functions

This is from Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook):

Show that $$ \min_{x \in \left\{x : c^T x +d > 0 \right\}} \ \frac{\|Ax-b\|_2^2}{c^T x + d} $$ has a minimizer $x^* = x_1 +t x_2$ where $$ x_1 = \left( A^T A \right)^{-1} A^T b, \qquad x_2=\left( A^T A \right)^{-1} c $$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is obtained by solving a quadratic equation.

---

From the structure of the solution, it seems like I am supposed to split the problem into two parts, but apart from that I don't really understad how to solve this. I tried to differentiate to find the minimizer, but I didn't get anything of this form. (In the problem before this, we had to show that $f$ is closed, if that is relevant).

Comment: Which section of the book?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us rewrite the problem to a convex optimization problem by adding a variable $s$:
$$\min \{ s||Ax-b||^2 : s = 1/(c^Tx + d) \}$$
and then substituting $y = xs$:
$$\min \{ s||A(y/s)-b||^2 : (c^Ty + ds) = 1 \}$$
Note that the objective function is the perspective of a convex function, and is therefore convex. The KKT stationarity conditions for $y$ and $s$ read:
$$2(A^TA(y/s)-A^Tb) + \lambda c = 0$$
$$-2\frac{||Ax||^2}{s^2} + b^T b + \lambda d = 0$$
The first condition can be solved for $y/s$:
$$x = \frac{y}{s} = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb-\frac{1}{2} \lambda (A^TA)^{-1} c$$
Your $t$ is now $-\lambda/2$. To find $\lambda$, consider the KKT stationarity condition for $s$, and plug in $s = 1/(c^Tx + d)$ to obtain the quadratic equation.

Comment: It's already a convex optimization problem as written; there's no need to "convert" it to one. Though of course your method works ;-)

Comment: @MichaelGrant ahh you are right, it's even a SOCP.

Comment: Well, not quite. It can be converted to an SOCP, but it is not an SOCP in its native form.

Comment: @MichaelGrant if we do not have norm-2 (i.e. $\|.\|^2$) and if $A$ is a vector then according to the LinAlg method the objective function will still be convex. But in Convex Optimization book it is written that it a linear fractional program and the objective function is quasiconvex. Doesn't it mean that there is some contradiction.

Comment: @LinAlg if we do not have norm-2 (i.e. $\|.\|^2$) and if $A$ is a vector then according to the your method the objective function will still be convex. But in Convex Optimization book it is written that it a linear fractional program and the objective function is quasiconvex. Doesn't it mean that there is some contradiction.

Comment: Trust @LinAlg. I see no contradiction. This is not linear fractional.

Comment: @FrankMoses the original objective is quasiconvex, but after the substitution it becomes convex. There is no contraduction. MichaelGrant: that is another comment of yours I have to frame now!