# Convexity of a rational objective function with quadratic numerator

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-fractional-transformation

I have a minimization problem where the objective is a rational function with a quadratic numerator and linear denominator, and where the constraints are linear inequalities.

$$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x_1, x_2} {\text{minimize}} & \dfrac{{\beta }_1{x_1}^2+{\beta }_2x_1x_2+{\beta }_3{x_2}^2}{h-{\alpha }_1x_1-{\alpha }_2x_2} =:z (x_1,x_2) \\ \text{subject to} & 0\le x_1\le 1 \\ & 0\le x_2\le 1 \end{array} $$

Note that for the denominator, $h-{\alpha }_1x_1-{\alpha }_2x_2>0$ is always valid, and all parameters ${\alpha }_1$, ${\alpha }_2$, ${\beta }_1$, ${\beta }_2$, ${\beta }_3$ and $h$ are positive real numbers. Is there any rule to show with what values of parameters the objective function is convex, concave, or non-convex?

Comment: You could introduce a variable $y$, write in epigraph form and obtain the following, which could be rewritten as a  quadratically-constrained linear program (QCLP) $$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x_1, x_2, y} {\text{minimize}} & y \\ \text{subject to} & \dfrac{{\beta }_1{x_1}^2+{\beta }_2x_1x_2+{\beta }_3{x_2}^2}{h-{\alpha }_1x_1-{\alpha }_2x_2} \leq y \\ & 0\le x_1\le 1 \\ & 0\le x_2\le 1 \end{array} $$

Comment: How is $h-{\alpha }_1x_1-{\alpha }_2x_2>0$ always valid? What if $h = 0^+$?

Comment: Thank you so much @RodrigodeAzevedo.  I need to consider h large enough (it reflects the capacity of some facilities in queuing theory) so that h−α1x1−α2x2>0. In other words, the rate of arrival rate of customers must be less than the service capacity so that we have a stationary situation.

Based on your conversion, can we conclude that if the numerator is convex and the denominator is concave or linear (but non-negative), then the objective function is also convex?

Comment: Take a look at my second comment.  If $h-{\alpha }_1x_1-{\alpha }_2x_2>0$, then you can multiply both sides of the inequality by $h-{\alpha }_1x_1-{\alpha }_2x_2$ and obtain an inequality defining a sub-level set of a quadratic function in $(x_1, x_2, y)$ and then you can use the Hessian to check convexity.

Comment: Thank you so much for this beneficial answer. Can do the same if the objective function is the summation of two fractional terms with a similar format?

Comment: Is the denominator the same?  I think it would be better to solve the optimization problem with a single term before getting too ambitious.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo

Dear Rodrigo, the second term is similar to the first term, but x_1 is changed to (1-x_1), and x_2 is changed to (1-x_2). Thank you so much for spending your valuable time.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, but I thought such a conversion is valid for one fractional term in the objective function, not a summation of two or more of them. Please note that for only one fractional term, there is also another way to convert the fraction to a quadratic function, but it may also not be valid for the summation. Please see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040031/minimizing-a-quadratic-over-linear-fractional-function

Comment: The question contains a single fractional term. You could try to start small. If you have two fractional terms, then introduce two decision variables, $y_1$ and $y_2$, and two quadratic inequalities of the aforementioned form

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank you so much, Rodrigo. I am following your suggestion. Thanks again.